# VBA to restore existing IE

Tags: vba, explorer

Code below

```
    Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
IE_count = objShell.Windows.Count
For x = 0 To (IE_count - 1)
    On Error Resume Next    ' sometimes more web pages are counted than are open
    my_url = objShell.Windows(x).document.Location
    my_title = objShell.Windows(x).document.Title
    If my_title Like "*" & "New" Then 
        Set IE = objShell.Windows(x)
AppActivate my_title
```

I only manage to activate the windows but not able to call it up when it is in the taskbar. Not able to find any code to restore.

Tried show window but not working

```
 Private Declare Function ShowWindow Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal nCmdShow As SHOW_WINDOW) As Boolean
```

Comment: Try using the `LocationName` property. E.g. `AppActivate IE.LocationName`

Comment: Thanks for looking into my problem. But this only help to bring IE to the front if it is not minimized. It didn't help to restore the windows

Comment: When you say restore what do you mean? The window is minimized? The window is invisible? Something else?

Comment: The window minimized into taskbar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

below is some code that will do the following:

1) Locate an Internet Explorer window by a partial Location Name. (Uses InStr())

2) Restore the window found using ShowWindow, then activate using the SetForegroundWindow windows API

Here's is the code, I tested this using Internet Explorer on my computer. It worked well.

Make sure you update the `WindowName` variable to be the name of the window you are searching for.

```
Private Const SW_SHOWNORMAL = 1
Private Const SW_MAXIMIZE = 3
Private Const SW_SHOW = 5
Private Const SW_MINIMIZE = 6
Private Const SW_RESTORE = 9

#If VBA7 Then
    Public Declare PtrSafe Function SetForegroundWindow Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long) As Long
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function ShowWindow Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal nCmdShow As Long) As Long
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function IsIconic Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal hwnd As Long) As Long
#Else
    Public Declare Function SetForegroundWindow Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long) As Long
    Private Declare Function ShowWindow Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal nCmdShow As Long) As Long
    Private Declare Function IsIconic Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal hwnd As Long) As Long
#End If

Public Sub Activate_A_Window()
    Dim IE As Object
    Dim Windows As Object: Set Windows = CreateObject("Shell.Application").Windows
    Dim Window As Object
    Dim my_title As String
    Dim WindowName As String: WindowName = "WindowNameGoesHere"

    For Each Window In Windows
        my_title = Window.LocationName
        If InStr(1, my_title, WindowName) Then
            Set IE = Window
            Exit For
        End If
    Next Window

    If Not IE Is Nothing Then 'Make sure IE was found as a window
        If CBool(IsIconic(IE.hwnd)) Then ' If it's minimized, show it
            ShowWindow IE.hwnd, SW_RESTORE
        End If

        SetForegroundWindow IE.hwnd 'Set the window as the foreground
    Else
        MsgBox (WindowName & " could not be located")
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help Ryan. It solved a lot of problem that I am facing in my project. Appreciated your time spending here.